# How to get the timestamp of each video frame in iOS while decoding a video.mp4

Tags: ios, objective-c, decoder, avassetreader, cmsamplebufferref

**Scenario:**
I am writing an *iOS app* to try decode a `videoFile.mp4`. I am using [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetreadertrackoutput) with [AVAssetReader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetreader) to decode frames from the video file. This works very well. I get each & every frame from `videoFile.mp4` basically using the following logic at the core.

**Code:**

```
AVAssetReader * videoFileReader;
AVAssetReaderTrackOutput * assetReaderOutput = [videoFileReader.outputs objectAtIndex:0];
CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [assetReaderOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
```

`sampleBuffer` is the buffer of each video frame here.

**Question:**

- *How* can I get the timestamp of each video frame here ?
- In other words & more detail, *how* can I get the timestamp of each `sampleBuffer` that i am returned from `copyNextSampleBuffer`?

**PS:**
Please note that I need the timestamp in *milliseconds*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the answer to my question finally. Following 2 lines can get the *frame timestamp* of the `sampleBuffer` returned from `copyNextSampleBuffer`

```
CMTime frameTime = CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
double frameTimeMillisecs = CMTimeGetSeconds(frameTime) * 1000;
```

Timestamp is returned in `seconds`. Hence multiplying it by `1000` to convert to `milliseconds`

Comment: hi, what would it be frameTimeMIllisecs? Is that the duration of the buffer? or the seconds from the referenceDate? something else?

Comment: `frameTimeMillisecs` is frame timestamp in milliseconds. Not seconds from reference date. It is rather seconds for 0 where 0 is the reference time  of the start of the video

Comment: Thank you! And how would you know the start of the video timestamp? Is it when startsession is called?